# How to access one control property in another control in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

> I want to access this.state.sampleString from HelloWorldApp component
>   class to CustomWebView component class in react native, but in alert
>   this.props.sampleString showing 'undefined'.

**Here is my code:**

```
class CustomWebView extends Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = { text: 'http://www.google.com' };
  }

  render() {
    alert(this.props.sampleString);
    return (

      <WebView 
      source={{uri:this.state.text}}
      style={{marginTop: 50}}
      />    

       );
  }

}

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { sampleString: 'http://www.google.com' };
    this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
  }

  getValue(){
    //console.log(this.state.sampleString);
    return this.state.sampleString
}

  handleClick = () => {
    alert(this.state.sampleString);
}

  render(){ 
    const {isFocused} = this.state;
    const{onFocus,onBlur} = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: 'column',
        height: '100%',
        paddingTop: 36
      }}>

    <View style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height : '5%',
      width : '100%',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      paddingBottom:3,
      paddingTop:1,
      marginTop : 20
    }}>

    <TextInput
    selectionColor = {BLUE}
    ref = "urltext"
    underlineColorAndroid={isFocused?BLUE:LIGHT_GRAY}
    onFocus = {this.handleFocus}
    onBlur ={this.handleBlur}
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={(sampleString) => this.setState({sampleString})}
    value={this.state.sampleString}
    />
    <Button title="Submit"
     onPress = {this.handleClick.bind(this)}
     color="#9933ff"
     accessibilityLabel="TestButton"/>



    </View>
    <CustomWebView/>
    </View>
    );
 }
```

}
})

I need to change url in class CustomWebView on the onPress event of Button in 
HelloWorldApp class. And that's why i want to access this.props.sampleString in CustomWebView class.

Answer (score 0):

use `CustomWebView` like this

```
<CustomWebView 
    sampleString={this.state.sampleString}
/>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Please do it as following:

```
<CustomWebView 
    sampleString={this.state.sampleString}
/>
```

on CustomWebView, you should use the props - `sampleString`, not state variable - `text`.

```
class CustomWebView extends Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = { text: 'http://www.google.com' };
  }

  render() {
    alert(this.props.sampleString);
    return (

      <WebView 
      source={{ uri: this.props.sampleString }}
      style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
      />    

       );
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually I want to set text from <TextInput> to source of <WebView> on click of button.

Comment: well.. then you need to use 2 state variables. one - text of textinput component, and the other one is to set the props of sampleString as same as the text of textinput when clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the wrong method to update the state at `onChangeText` as,

```
onChangeText={(sampleString) => this.setState({sampleString})}
```

when you use above method you can get an error like,

> sampleState is not defined

because you have to define which state you want to update with the updated value in `setState` method. You have to update state as,

```
onChangeText={(inputText) => this.setState({sampleString: inputText})}
```

And then you can pass this sampleString in `CustomWebView` as prop,

```
<CustomWebView uri = {this.state.sampleString} />
```

Finally, you can access this prop in CustomWebView as,

```
<WebView 
  source={{ uri: this.props.uri }}
  style={{ marginTop: 50 }}
/>
```

And all done :)

**Note: -** Because you are updating state at `onChangeText`, and simultaneously passing this state as prop in CustomWebView. CustomWebView can access this state without button click.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take two state variable. fist for **textInput** and second is for **rendering Webview**, which you have to pass in CustomWebView component.
Your HelloWorldApp class should be like following:

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     textInputData: 'http://www.google.com'
     sampleString: 'http://www.google.com' 
   };
  }

  handleClick(){
   //set sampleString when click on button
   this.setState({
      sampleString: this.state.textInputData
    })
}

  render(){ 
    const {isFocused} = this.state;
    const{onFocus,onBlur} = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: 'column',
        height: '100%',
        paddingTop: 36
      }}>

    <View style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height : '5%',
      width : '100%',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      paddingBottom:3,
      paddingTop:1,
      marginTop : 20
    }}>

    <TextInput
    selectionColor = {BLUE}
    ref = "urltext"
    underlineColorAndroid={isFocused?BLUE:LIGHT_GRAY}
    onFocus = {this.handleFocus}
    onBlur ={this.handleBlur}
    style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={(inputText) => this.setState({textInputData: inputText})}
    value={this.state.textInputData}
    />
    <Button title="Submit"
     onPress = {this.handleClick.bind(this)}
     color="#9933ff"
     accessibilityLabel="TestButton"/>
    </View>
    <CustomWebView
     sampleString={this.state.sampleString} />
    </View>
    );
 }
} })
```

and you will get updated sampleString in **componentWillReceiveProps()** of CustomWebView component

```
class CustomWebView extends Component{
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = { 
text: 'http://www.google.com'
 };
  }
  componentWillMount(){
   this.setState({ text:this.props.sampleString })
 }
 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  //when will you update url in textinput and do submit. you will get updated 
   sampleString here.
   this.setState({ text:newProps.sampleString })
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView 
      source={{uri:this.state.text}}
      style={{marginTop: 50}}
      />    

       );
  }
}
```